# How to test getter, setter method of a LiveData Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, android-unit-testing

I am using Hilt for DI in my project. I am trying write unit test cases for LiveData object, but it's not coming under coverage.

**ViewModel**

```
@HiltViewModel
class HealthDiagnosticsViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private var networkHelper: NetworkHelper
) : ViewModel() {

    var result = MutableLiveData<Int>()

    .....

}
```

My unit test class is as below:

**HealthViewModelTest**

```
@HiltAndroidTest
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
@Config(application = HiltTestApplication::class)
class HealthDiagnosticsViewModelTest{

    @get:Rule
    var hiltRule = HiltAndroidRule(this)

    @Inject
    lateinit var networkHelper: NetworkHelper

    lateinit var healthDiagnosticsViewModel: HealthDiagnosticsViewModel

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        hiltRule.inject()
        healthDiagnosticsViewModel = HealthDiagnosticsViewModel(networkHelper)
    }

    @Test
    fun testGetResult() {
        val result = healthDiagnosticsViewModel.result.value
        Assert.assertEquals(null, result)
    }

    @Test
    fun testSetResult() {
        healthDiagnosticsViewModel.result.value = 1
        Assert.assertEquals(1, healthDiagnosticsViewModel.result.value)
    }
}
```

Test Cases are passed but it's not coming under method coverage.

Comment: Could share the logic of your functions?

Answer (score 0):

I'll share with you the an example of my code that would solve your problem.

I'm usnig **ViewModel** with **Dagger Hilt**

1. You don't have to use Robelectric, you can use [MockK library](https://mockk.io/#installation).
2. Replace your HiltRule with this Rule:

   @get:Rule

   var rule: TestRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()
3. This is my ViewModel class

using MockK, you can mock the networkHelper class without Hilt.
So, your setup method will be like that:

```
lateinit var networkHelper: NetworkHelper
......
......
......
@Before
fun setUp() {
    networkHelper = mockk<NetworkHelper>()
    healthDiagnosticsViewModel = HealthDiagnosticsViewModel(networkHelper)
}
```

4)The most important part in your test is **to Observe to the LiveData first**.

```
@Test
fun testGetResult() {
    healthDiagnosticsViewModel.result.observeForever {}
    val result = healthDiagnosticsViewModel.result.value
    Assert.assertEquals(null, result)
}
```

You can observe to the livedata for each unit test, but keep in mind to ***Observe first*** before change data.

Comment: Can we use `HiltRule` instead of TestRule ?

Comment: Most of cases HiltAndroidRule, used in UI testing. Here you are testing a ViewModel. where no need for this rule.

Comment: Does it solve your problem?

Comment: test getting passed, that's not the issue. Issue is it's not covered inside Coverage.